# Max/min for calculus

Tags: calculus

I was having some trouble finding the max/min for this question. The function is 
$$f(x)= x^2 (\ln(x))$$ I need to find the first derivative to find critical values to find max/min and then second derivative for points of inflection. How would i set those detivatives equal to zero to find the critival values?

Comment: By following the procedures you outline. Find $f'(x), f''(x)$. Then solve $f'(x) = 0$, $f''(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we get $f'(x)=x(2\ln(x)+1)$ thus we get $f'(x)=0$ if $2\ln(x)+1=0$ this gives $x=e^{-1/2}$
since $x=0$ is impossible. Further we get
$f''(x)=2\ln(x)+3$
we have $f''(e^{-1/2})=2\cdot(-1/2)+3=2>0$ thus we have a minimum for $x=e^{-1/2}$
$x=e^{-1/2}$ gives a minimum since $f''(e^{-1/2})=2>0$

Comment: So for the first derivative there are no max/min values?

Comment: It makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use the product rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(g(x)h(x))= g'(x)h(x)+g(x)h'(x).$$

In your case $g(x)=x^2$ and $h(x)=\ln x$.

When you have the derivative $f'(x)$, then set it to $0$ to see where the function stops momentarily increasing or decreasing (where the slope is $0$). Next, solve $f(x)=0.$

Now you would take the second derivative which will tell whether a critical point is a maximum or a minimum.

Comment: For the detivative i got f'(x)= x+2xlnx. How do i solve that to get a max or min point?